# How can I force the keyboard to stay displayed?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an IBAction that is called when someone is done entering text in a field.  I then validate the input.  If I have determined there is an error, I display a message and want the user to enter into that same field again.  Rather than make them select the text field to bring the keyboard up (which works fine) I want to just leave the keyboard displayed.

I am doing `[SymbolEntered becomeFirstResponder];` as the last statement in my IBAction, but the keyboard still goes away.  Am I putting that in the wrong place?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {

    DebugMsg.text = nil;
    DebugMsg2.text = nil;
    DebugMsg3.text = nil;

    NSLog (@"done editing");
    NSLog (@"%@", SymbolEntered.text);

    if ([SymbolEntered.text isEqualToString:nil])
    {
        Result.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        Result.text = @"You must enter a symbol!";
        [SymbolEntered becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else 
    {
        if ([SymbolEntered.text isEqualToString: 
             [NSString stringWithCString:elements_table2[el_tbl_idx-1].element_symbol]])
        {
            correct_count++;
            Result.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            Result.text = @"Correct!";
            Score.hidden = FALSE;
            Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d out of %d - %d Percent", correct_count, el_count+1,
                                        (correct_count*100)/(el_count+1)];
            GetNextElementButton.hidden = FALSE;
            SymbolEntered.enabled = FALSE;
            el_count++;
            attempts = max_tries + 1;
        } 
        else 
        {
            Score.hidden = TRUE;
            Result.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            if (attempts < max_tries)
            {
                if (attempts+1 == max_tries)
                {
                    Result.text = @"Sorry, one more try -";
                }
                else
                {    
                    Result.text = @"Sorry, try again - ";
                }
                GetNextElementButton.hidden = TRUE;
                attempts++;
            }
            else
            {    
                Result.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Sorry.  The correct answer is %@", 
                   [NSString stringWithCString:elements_table2[el_tbl_idx-1].element_symbol]];
                Score.hidden = FALSE;
                Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d out of %d - %d Percent", correct_count, el_count+1,                      (correct_count*100)/(el_count+1)];
                GetNextElementButton.hidden = FALSE;
                SymbolEntered.enabled = FALSE;
                el_count++;
            }
        }
    }   

    [SymbolEntered becomeFirstResponder];        

    NSLog (@"end of textfieldoneediting");
}
```

Comment: Is `resignFirstResponder` called anywhere in your source code?

Comment: Not in this IBAction, but it is called in an IBAction for a background tap when the keyboard is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do your validation in the UITextField textFieldShouldEndEditing: delegate method instead. If you return NO from that callback, the text field will remain first responder and the keyboard won't go away. (You'll have to make your controller object the text field's delegate if it isn't already, of course.)

Comment: Sounds great, but I have to admit I am a novice at this.  I don't understand the delegate business.  Could you add a little more about how to do this or send me to some documentation that would explain it?  Thanks, and sorry for the delay in responding but I was unable to get back to this until just now.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the [textField becomeFirstResponder] sometime later? Also make sure the UITextField pointer is not nil or something. For more help please show some of your code, it's very hard to tell where the problem is like this.

Comment: I am calling the becomeFirstResponder as the very last statement.  How do I display the code so it is formatted properly on this site?

Comment: Code should be above.  I hope.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;
}
```

Try This it will resign the keyboard.